# Authentication in Symfony2 without being able to read the password

Tags: symfony

I'm writing my first Symfony2 app after a few years with Symfony and am having trouble converting our user management code. It seems that to fit in with Symfony2's authentication model I have to provide user details including their (encrypted) passwords. We authenticate via a webservice that takes the username and password and responds with a confirmation and user level (user, admin etc), but it never sends the real password back to us.

What I want to do is accept the login details from a form, confirm they are valid and then set the user's roles according to the webservice's response. Where do I start?

Comment: Two good answers below, I'm working through the full official way from symfony.com with the authentication provider pinging the webservice part way through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom authentication provider to authenticate against your webservice. It is explained quite clearly in this blog [post](http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/)

Comment: I'm looking through that tutorial and trying to grab the bits that are similar to mine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an user provider and its `loadUserByName` you can call the webservice. If success return the new `UserInterface` object with the password of the form empty salt string and the roles returned by the service. Also set encoder of the `UserInterface` to plaintext in `security.yml`. And then set the new created user provider in `form_login` auth provider in the firewall.

Comment: You are assuming here that passwords are not encrypted in the web service, which should not be a valid scenario. If passwords are encrypted, this solution is not valid unless we know the encryption mechanism that the web service is using in order to configure security.yml.